# what does "// /_" mean in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am currently moving our shell/bash scripts from a jenkinsfile to groovy scripts that are stored in methods but still execute as sh scripts.

The issue i have is with variables containing // /_

exmaple:

```
${VARIABLE_NAME// /_}
```

I cannot find what // /_ exactly does when supplied like this in a variable.
I need to find another way to do this because when moved to Groovy methods, it causes formating issues where escaping doesnt work properly.

Comment: It will replace all spaces with underscores.

Answer (score 1):

It will replace all spaces with underscores.

Consider the following example:

```
$ var='hello world john doe'
$ echo "${var// /_}"
hello_world_john_doe
$
```

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. The match is performed according to the rules described below (see Pattern Matching). **If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the first match is replaced.** If pattern begins with ‘#’, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins with ‘%’, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter. If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted. If the nocasematch shell option (see the description of shopt in The Shopt Builtin) is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Copied from: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html with my emphasize on how `/` and `//` differences.

Comment: Yes, great explanation thanks! but is there any other way to achieve the same?
When stored in groovy scripts, the // part will cause the rest of the line to be recognized for some reason as a comment, creating problems in the rest of script.

Comment: You can pipe to `tr` (translate) to convert the spaces to underscores. `echo "hello world john doe" | tr ' ' '_'` will output `hello_world_john_doe` and in your case that would be: `echo "$VARIABLE_NAME" | tr ' ' '_'`